Can I process pyroxene or olivine as a part of magnesium thermite?
It is possible for $\ce{Mg}$ to rip oxygen from $\ce{SiO2}$. Sand and magnesium burn in a thermite-like reaction and produce silicon and an oxide.
$$\ce{2 Mg + SiO2 -> 2 MgO + Si + \text{energy}}$$
It means that it is possible to break $\ce{Si-O}$ bonds by reduction with $\ce{Mg}$.
What products can I obtain if olivine or pyroxene are burnt in the same way?

Pyroxene: $\ce{XX^\prime Si2O6}$, where $\ce{X = Fe, Mg}$ and $\ce{X^\prime = Mg, Ti, Al, Fe}$

Olivine: $\ce{(Mg, Fe)SiO4}$


The aim of this reaction is to obtain metals trapped in olivine or pyroxene.
$$\ce{Mg + XX^\prime Si2O6 -> MgO + ??}$$
$$\ce{Mg + (Mg, Fe)SiO4 -> MgO + ??}$$
If it's even possible, at what approximate temperature will the reaction ignite?
P.S. For context: this is for a fictional setting. I am writing about asteroid mining and need some help with realism for stone asteroid processing. I am not very good at chemistry and that's why I am here.

EDIT: I messed up $Mg$ and $Mn$. It should be magnesium thermite not manganese
EDIT: I found a source for magnesium reaction with silicon dioxide, updated the question with a more relevant example, and removed unnecessary details.

Manganese dioxide can be oxidiser I think you got it mixed up.

Pyroxene and olivine are both minerals containing magnesium ions. So these magnesium ions will probably prevent a thermite reaction produced by mixing one of these minerals with metallic magnesium powder.

Y R U using Y as a symbol for something other than yttrium? Also. the title has still "manganese" in it.

@PaulKolk, thanks! I fixed the title. Y is a variable element as pyroxene could have different formulas. I took it strait from wikipedia page

@PaulKolk Easy, man! X any Y are sometimes used for generic xhemical symbols. If the nomenclature is explained as it is here, there is no real problem.

Now there is another ambiguity: "magnesium thermite" in the title and "aluminum thermite" in the text referring to different types of things - there is no pure magnesium metal, whereas aluminum metal is a reducing agent. I prefer to change "Y" , because it makes reading easier. You decide, however.

Or, alternatively, if there is magnesium as a reducing agent, then obviously, magnesium compounds cannot be reduced by it.

@PaulKolk, I have changed the notation and specified what I want to achieve with this reaction

Yes, you actually somewhat can
TLDR: go to the bottom.

Disclamer
I am not good at chemistry, so please leave feedback if you think that something is wrong here. The ideas for this answer are very inspired by this video about Lunar regolith processing.

Theory
At first, one needs to consult the diagrams. More precisely, the Ellingham diagram.

There is a lot going on here, but, in a nutshell, metals that are lower can steal oxygen from those that are higher.
For example, $Ca$ can steal from everybody, while $Mg$ is the next best thing before reaching 1500-ish °C. After this temperature $Al$ takes its place.
Moreover, at any temperature, provided the reaction is ignited, $Mg$ could steal electrons from $Si$.
Pyroxene structure
The image is taken from pyroxene Wikipedia page.

It shows that oxygen is bound not only to $Si$ but to metals as well. This supports the claim that indeed it is impossible to process $Mg$-containing pyroxene via $Mg$.
However, everything else, besides $Ca$, $Mg$, and conditionally $Al$, is a fair game.
So, to answer the question about the pyroxene reaction in question:
$
\ce{6Mg + XX'Si2O6 -> 6MgO + XX'Si2_{alloy}} + energy
$, where $X$ and $X'$ are any pyroxene eligible metals except $Mg$, $Ca$ and, conditionally, $Al$. This is inferred from a similar olivine reaction with $Ca$
It seems like the ignition temperature should be the same order of magnitude as in $\ce{2Mg + SiO2 -> 2MgO + Si}$ reaction, which is around 650 °C if no free oxygen is present and particles are 10 nm in size.
Olivine structure
The image is taken from olivine Wikipedia page.

The same line of thought applies to olivine as in pyroxene. Thus, only fayalites can be processed this way with $Fe$ ions in M1 and M2 positions.
$$\ce{4Mg + Fe2SiO4 -> 4MgO + Fe2Si_{alloy}} + energy$$
The information about ignition temperatures for these reactions is sparse, so I will speculate that they are roughly the same as with sand: 650 °C.
Conclusion
It seems like $Ca$ is kinda a better choice for these shenanigans as it can reduce even $Mg$.

$\ce{4Mg + Fe2SiO4 -> 4MgO + Fe2Si_{alloy}} + energy$

$
\ce{6Mg + XX'Si2O6 -> 6MgO + XX'Si2_{alloy}} + energy
$, where $X$ and $X'$ are any pyroxene eligible metals except $Mg$, $Ca$ and, conditionally, $Al$.


